# What to use istead of THIS in php OOP?

Tags: php, oop, class, this

I have a static class that loads additional php file inside of one of its function and I need to access class variables from this file withous knowing the class name.

But This::SomeVar - doesn't work.

But I know there's another way to do it, I just can't find anything about it.

So here's the example class

```
class SomeClass {
    static function Initialize() {
        require_once 'somefile.php';
    }
}
```

and inside that file I need to access static variable something like this

```
This::SomeVar= 'qwe';
```

Comment: Have you tried "$this->SomeVar" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self::$SomeVar` to access static class members.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->someVar` for fields and `self::$someVar` for statics

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->someVar` to access a property from inside a class.

Comment: This works if I have an object of the class, but I need to access static variable.

Comment: Ah, in that case `self::$someVar` should do it.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I was looking for :)